# ldapsearch returns result, but getent does not

Tags: centos, openldap, ldap

I am setting up a fresh CentOS 7 server to and need to setup LDAP authentication i.e. there already exists a server that authenticates users, which we use for other GNU/Linux servers.

For instance, in Windows I can query the hostname and IP of the DC using `nltest /dclist:X.Y`. Which returns a list of DC servers which I can confirm are correct.

When I test connection to these DC servers using `ldapsearch` on the CentOS 7 server it works:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://<DCSERVER> -D <user>@X.Y -w
```

Output is a long list of information, including DN information.

However, when using `getent passwd`, there is no output, and error I see in /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 24 16:09:37 XXXXXXXX nslcd[22440]: [16e9e8] <passwd(all)> ldap_result() failed: Operations error: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C09072B, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580
```

`getent password` works fine on other CentOS 6 servers, but they are using BeyondTrust, which I want to migrate away from and I was not the admin at the time of installation.

Relevant config files:

`/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` contains:

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/pki/tls/certs

# Turning this off breaks GSSAPI used with krb5 when rdns = false
SASL_NOCANON    on
URI ldap://<DCSERVER>
BASE DC=X,DC=Y
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` contiains:

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#       nisplus                 Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#       nis                     Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#       dns                     Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#       files                   Use the local files
#       db                      Use the local database (.db) files
#       compat                  Use NIS on compat mode
#       hesiod                  Use Hesiod for user lookups
#       [NOTFOUND=return]       Stop searching if not found so far
#

# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
#initgroups: files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

`/etc/nslcd.conf` contains:

```
# This is the configuration file for the LDAP nameservice
# switch library's nslcd daemon. It configures the mapping
# between NSS names (see /etc/nsswitch.conf) and LDAP
# information in the directory.
# See the manual page nslcd.conf(5) for more information.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid ldap

# The uri pointing to the LDAP server to use for name lookups.
# Multiple entries may be specified. The address that is used
# here should be resolvable without using LDAP (obviously).
#uri ldap://127.0.0.1/
#uri ldaps://127.0.0.1/
#uri ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fldapi_sock/
# Note: %2f encodes the '/' used as directory separator
uri ldap://<DCSERVER>

# The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3
# if supported by client library)
#ldap_version 3

# The distinguished name of the search base.
base DC=X,DC=Y

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with.
# Optional: default is to bind anonymously.
#binddn cn=proxyuser,dc=example,dc=com
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mismatch: if you check the sssd logs, you are using the sssd daemon. But then you should configure it in the file:

```
/etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

not in /etc/nslcd.conf (good for the pam-ldapd daemon).

Moreover:

1. syntax of sssd.conf and nslcd.conf is very different;
2. in /etc/nsswitch.conf, sssd daemon is referenced with the 'sss' key (not 'ldap').

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this completely.

However, inspection of the `/var/log/sssd/sssd_DOMAIN.log` revealed that SSS is working but likely issue with improperly specified DN?

```
(Tue Nov 25 16:21:16 2014) [sssd[be[LDI.LAN]]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: ldap_result found nothing!
(Tue Nov 25 16:21:16 2014) [sssd[be[LDI.LAN]]] [sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0x7fc9553ddde0], connected[1], ops[0x7fc9553ed2c0], ldap[0x7fc9553d0cb0]
(Tue Nov 25 16:21:16 2014) [sssd[be[LDI.LAN]]] [sdap_process_message] (0x4000): Message type: [LDAP_RES_SEARCH_RESULT]
(Tue Nov 25 16:21:16 2014) [sssd[be[LDI.LAN]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_done] (0x0400): Search result: Operations error(1), 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090724, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v23f0
```

In the end, I chose to use open source PBIS from Beyond Trust. Worked in few minutes.

http://www.beyondtrust.com/Resources/OpenSourceDocumentation/